# Error using tool Split lines at points

Tags: qgis, splitting

When using the tool split lines at points, the line splits in places where there are no cutting points. I use a 1m epsilon.
In the first image you can see the line to be cut with the lilac point

[image: Image_01]

In the following image you can see the result where the line was cut in a place where there is no point.

[image: Image_02]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Check the vertices of the original line, as the new small line is 1) cut at the expected (left) point  and 2) it is also cut at another location that seems aligned with the 3rd point and "perpendicular but not connected" segment. Check for surprises as segments parts (from the multilinestring) or fully invalid lines, like making a "collapsed" Z shape.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What you wrote is useful when the data is not much, since you can make modifications manually.  My data are more than 1000 and I would like to look for a tool that allows to automate the task.